# Martingale and heat equation: a check one the martingale property

Tags: brownian-motion, conditional-expectation, martingales, heat-equation, fubini-tonelli-theorems

I need a check on the following exercise, which is the same situation that the user @saz proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1494883/extension-of-dynkins-formula-conclude-that-process-is-a-martingale/1513025#1513025) with all the details. The fact is that  the notation is a bit a problem for me and I'd like to be sure that what I've worked out is fine.

---

> Let $f$ be a $C^2$ function on $\mathbb{R}$  such that $f,f',f''$ are bounded and consider the random variable $W_t$ of density $p_t(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi t}} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2t}}$.
>
> We know from the lectures that  that $$E[f(W_t) - f(W_0)] = \frac{1}{2} E[\int_0^t f''(W_u)du]$$ (Use the fact that $p_t(x)$ solves the heat equation and Fubini thm)
>
> Prove now that the process defined by $$M_t=f(W_t)-f(W_0) - \frac{1}{2} \int_0^t f''(W_u)du$$ is a $(F_t)_t$ martingale.

---

To this aim, I fix $0<s<t$ and compute as usual:
$$E[M_t - M_s|F_s] = E[f(W_t) - f(W_s)- \frac{1}{2} \int_s^t f''(W_u)du|F_s]$$

First, I note that by the **Freezing lemma** (F.L.), the first two summands are respectively 
$$E[f(W_t)]$$
$$E[f(W_s)]$$

Now I focus on $E[\int_s^t f''(W_u)du|F_s]$, which is equal, by **Fubini**, to: $$\int_s^t E[f''(W_u)|F_s] du = \\ \int_s^t E[f''( (W_u-W_s) + W_s) |F_s ]=_{F.L.} \\ \int_s^t E[f''(W_u)]du  =_{FUB} \\ E[\int_s^t f''(B_u) du]$$

Collecting everything together:$$E[f(W_t) - f(W_0) - \frac{1}{2} \int_s^t f''(W_u) du]$$

Now, repeating exactly the argument I used to show that $\star$, I conclude that $$E[f(W_t) - f(W_0) - \frac{1}{2} \int_s^t f''(W_u) du]=0$$

and hence the thesis follows.

**Is everything okay? Especially the application of the freezing lemma on the integral term**

Comment: Sorry it's a typo. I have fixed it now :)