# Exercise book on Brownian motion

Tags: probability, reference-request, brownian-motion, book-recommendation

for my exam of stochastic I will have some exercise on Brownian motion. We covered from the construction of Brownian motion, we showed the basic properties (up to reflection principle) and also talk about the stopping theorem.

In the lectures we had just not much exercises. I'd like to know some books /exercise book with lots of exercises and possibly solutions. Also some past exams "repo" of some professor is okay.

The level of our exercise is quite standard: for instance we showed the martingality property of Brownian motion, we computed the covariance of a Brownian bridge or we have exercises where we are required to use the stopping theorem.

Comment: Take a look at the Brownian motion book by Schilling & Partzsch; the solutions to the exercise are available on the webpage of the auhors.

Comment: Thanks! I'll have a look now!

Comment: Really good resource, thank you @saz ! :)

Comment: You are welcome; glad I could help you.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you, but yesterday I asked a question about an answer that you gave (you followed the proof given in the book suggested above). Could you just tell me if my argument seems okay? It's almost the same you gave, but I'd like to be sure. 

If you have time, here's the link :https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3507912/martingale-and-heat-equation-a-check-one-the-martingale-property